# How to wait for get request without freezing client

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple button which sends a get request to retrieve a txt file on my website. Problem is it freezes the application while retrieving the info. How can I make it so the application doesn't freeze while waiting for the result?

```
Private Sub cmd_ClickMe_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmd_ClickMe.Click
    Dim request As String = String.Format("http://www.*****/database/test.txt")
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString(request)

    MessageBox.Show(result)
End Sub
```

I've also tried the following but it doesn't work (says "webClient.DownloadStringAsync(myUri)" does not produce a value:

```
Private Sub cmd_ClickMe_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmd_ClickMe.Click
    Dim request As String = String.Format("http://www.****.com/database/test.txt")
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim myUri As Uri = New Uri(request)

    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadStringAsync(myUri)

    MessageBox.Show(result)
End Sub
```

Comment: you would want to offload this to a separate thread to prevent the UI from becoming unresponsive during processing. here's some info for doing so, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719109(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Use `DownloadStringAsync(Uri)` instead of the `DownloadString(uri)`.

The `DownloadStringAsync` method does not block the calling thread.

Here is an example how to use it:

```
    Dim wc As New WebClient
    '  Specify that you get alerted 
    '  when the download completes.
    AddHandler wc.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf AlertStringDownloaded

    Dim uri As New Uri("http:\\changeMe.com")  'Pass the URL to here. This is just an example
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(uri)

End Sub

Public Shared Sub AlertStringDownloaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)

    '  If the string request went as planned and wasn't cancelled:
    If e.Cancelled = False AndAlso e.Error Is Nothing Then

        Dim myString As String = CStr(e.Result)   'Use e.Result to get the String
        MessageBox.Show(myString)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: With that I'm getting the following error: "Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Uri'"

Comment: If you pass a string and not an uri object that is a reasonable error message. Create an uri object from your string : Dim myUri As Uri = New Uri(request) and pass that to the async method.

Comment: I've added that but I get the error: "Expression does not produce a value". I added that code to my question above

Comment: Async requires you to register a callback. But I understand from your updated question and your comment that you need a more complete example. Thus I updated my answer.

Comment: Ah thanks the code itself works, but the client still freezes while waiting for the get response. I guess it just doesn't freeze while downloading? The file is very small anyway, but yes it still freezes while waiting for the actual response back.

Comment: The point of async is that it won't freeze the thread it's called from. Make sure you are calling it as he wrote it (DownloadStringAsync NOT DownloadString). DownloadStringAsync is not a blocking call and will not freeze your main thread. When it completes, it should raise the event which he subscribed to in the `AddHandler ...` line.

Comment: I copied the code exactly. I'm thinking that maybe it's freezing waiting for the response not necessarilly when it's downloading. I've solved the problem now using a background_worker.